# lstlisting: do not tread include-file as a keyword

Tags: listings, include, keywords

I am writing some C++ listings. I would prefer some more keyword highlighting (for `cout`,
`cerr`, `endl`, `ifstream`, `string`, etc.). However, when I define `string` as a keyword, also
the `#include` directive highlights.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
   language=c++,
   keywordstyle=\color{red},
   morekeywords={string, cout, endl}
]
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

string s;
cout << s << endl;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: lstlisting]

I would prefer that the word `string` after `#include` is not highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an exception for the `<string>` part of the text.
This is not a perfect solution but it works. I've moved all the options in `\lstset` block.

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
   language=c++,   
   mathescape,   
   morekeywords={string, cout, endl},keywordstyle=\color{red},
   morecomment=[l][\color{black}]{<string>}
}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

string s;
cout << s << endl;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Dušan,

Thank you for your reply. Your solution works.

However, I posted a MWE and my problem is a little more complex.

- I use ``\lstdefinelanguage`` to define my own C++ stuff
- I use ``\lstset`` to define global stuff (like ``showstringspaces``)
- I use ``\lstdefinestyle`` *multiple times* to define styles (dark powerpoint, light powerpoint, BW)

So when defining a language (like C++), I am not aware of the colors or fonts that are used by the ``\lstdefinestyle``.

Can I add something within ``\\lstdefinelanguage`` without the knowledge of the current color, font, etc.?

Comment: I'm kinda stuck here. Anyone else?